# How to enable both page indicator and more options in a wearable web TIZEN app?

Tags: html, css, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

By changing 'data-enable-page-scroll' to true or false, it either enables one feature or another, in addition to messing up the positions of the section. 'false' enables 'pageindicator' and the page looks perfect, however, the 'moreoptions' doesn't work. Now if I turn it is 'true', 'moreoptions' work, but not the page indicator, furthermore, the whole page seems to move quite a bit downwards on the watch.

By 'pageindicator' not working, I mean it doesn't show up on the top of the page (at all).
By 'moreoptions' not working, I mean that it does show the 3 dots on the right side (it is also properly indented), however, it does not show 'moreoptionsPopupCircle' on the screen. Furthermore, there is no animation when I touch the button as if it was just some static element in the screen.

Device: Gear S3 Frontier

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Wearable UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" href="/lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" href="/lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="application">
    <div id="pageIndicatorPage" class="ui-page" data-enable-page-scroll="true">
        <button type="button" class="ui-more">More Options</button>
        <div id="pageIndicator" class="ui-page-indicator"></div>
        <div id="hsectionchanger" class="ui-content">
            <div>
                <section class="ui-section-active section" style="text-align:center">
                    <header id="main">Main</header>
                    <div id="a" class="positive-left circle-button"></div>
                </section>
                <section class="section" style="text-align:center">
                    <header id="main2">b</header>
                    <div id="b" class="positive-left circle-button"></div>circle-button"></div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Circle Profile -->
        <div id="moreoptionsPopupCircle" class="ui-popup">
            <div id="selector" class="ui-selector">
                <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
                <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
                <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
                <div class="ui-item x-icon" data-title="X Icon"></div>
                <div class="ui-item fail-icon" data-title="Fail"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="moreoptions.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/circle-helper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pageindicator.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

moreoptions.js: http://pastebin.com/Ykx1E49v

pageindicator.js: http://pastebin.com/C28V9Jfa

style.css: http://pastebin.com/7pwGqnMz

style-main.css: http://pastebin.com/J1MW8Zyx

Comment: Please also add your JS code for both Indicator and Moreoption

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript code to make it functional.

```
<body>
    <div id="hsectionchangerPage" class="ui-page" data-enable-page-scroll="false">
        <div id="pageIndicator" class="ui-page-indicator"></div>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/sectionchanger.css">
        <div class="ui-content content-padding">
                <button type="button" class="ui-more">More Options</button>
        </div>
        <div id="hsectionchanger" class="ui-content">
            <!-- section changer has only one child. -->
            <div>
                <section style="text-align:center" >
                    <h3> LEFT2 PAGE </h3>
                </section>
                <section style="text-align:center">
                    <h3> LEFT1 PAGE </h3>
                </section>
                <section class="ui-section-active" style="text-align:center">
                    <h3> MAIN PAGE </h3>
                </section>
                <section style="text-align:center">
                    <h3> RIGHT1 PAGE </h3>
                </section>
                <section style="text-align:center">
                    <h3> RIGHT2 PAGE </h3>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Square Profile -->
    <div id="moreoptionsPopup" class="ui-popup" data-transition="slideup">
        <div class="ui-popup-header">Options</div>
        <div class="ui-popup-content">
            <ul class="ui-listview">
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Circle Profile -->
    <div id="moreoptionsPopupCircle" class="ui-popup">
        <div id="selector" class="ui-selector">
            <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
            <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
            <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
            <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
            <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
            <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
            <div class="ui-item x-icon" data-title="X Icon"></div>
            <div class="ui-item fail-icon" data-title="Fail"></div>
            <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
            <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
            <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
            <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
            <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
            <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
            <div class="ui-item x-icon" data-title="X Icon"></div>
            <div class="ui-item fail-icon" data-title="Fail"></div>
            <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
            <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
            <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
            <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
            <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
            <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
            <div class="ui-item x-icon" data-title="X Icon"></div>
            <div class="ui-item fail-icon" data-title="Fail"></div>
            <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
            <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
            <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
            <div class="ui-item show-icon" data-title="Show"></div>
            <div class="ui-item human-icon" data-title="Human"></div>
            <div class="ui-item delete-icon" data-title="Delete"></div>
            <div class="ui-item x-icon" data-title="X Icon"></div>
            <div class="ui-item fail-icon" data-title="Fail"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="hsection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="moreoptions.js"></script>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

**hsection.js**

```
(function() {

    var page = document.getElementById( "hsectionchangerPage" ),
        changer = document.getElementById( "hsectionchanger" ),
        sectionLength = document.querySelectorAll("section").length,
        elPageIndicator = document.getElementById("pageIndicator"),
        sectionChanger,
        pageIndicator,
        pageIndicatorHandler;

    /**
     * pagebeforeshow event handler
     * Do preparatory works and adds event listeners
     */
    page.addEventListener( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
        // make PageIndicator
        pageIndicator =  tau.widget.PageIndicator(elPageIndicator, { numberOfPages: sectionLength });
        pageIndicator.setActive(2);
        // make SectionChanger object
        sectionChanger = tau.widget.SectionChanger(changer, {
            circular: false,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            useBouncingEffect: true
        });
    });

    /**
     * pagehide event handler
     * Destroys and removes event listeners
     */
    page.addEventListener( "pagehide", function() {
        // release object
        sectionChanger.destroy();
    });

    /**
     * sectionchange event handler
     */
    pageIndicatorHandler = function (e) {
        pageIndicator.setActive(e.detail.active);
    };

    changer.addEventListener("sectionchange", pageIndicatorHandler, false);

}());
```

**moreoptions.js**

```
/*global tau */
/*jslint unparam: true */
(function(){
    /**
     * page - More option page element
     * popup - More option popup element for rectangular devices
     * handler - Element for opening more option popup
     * popupCircle - More option popup element for circular devices
     * elSelector - Selector element in the circular popup
     * selector - TAU selector instance
     */
    var page = document.querySelector("#hsectionchangerPage"),
        popup = page.querySelector("#moreoptionsPopup"),
        handler = page.querySelector(".ui-more"),
        popupCircle = page.querySelector("#moreoptionsPopupCircle"),
        elSelector = page.querySelector("#selector"),
        selector,
        clickHandlerBound;

    /**
     * Click event handler for opening more option popup
     */
    function clickHandler() {
        if (tau.support.shape.circle) {
            tau.openPopup(popupCircle);
        } else {
            tau.openPopup(popup);
        }
    }

    /**
     * pagebeforeshow event handler
     * Do preparatory works and adds event listeners
     */
    page.addEventListener( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
        var radius = window.innerHeight / 2 * 0.8;

        clickHandlerBound = clickHandler.bind(null);
        handler.addEventListener("click", clickHandlerBound);
        if (tau.support.shape.circle) {
            selector = tau.widget.Selector(elSelector, {itemRadius: radius});
        }
    });

    /**
     * pagebeforehide event handler
     * Destroys and removes event listeners
     */
    page.addEventListener( "pagebeforehide", function() {
        handler.removeEventListener("click", clickHandlerBound);
        if (tau.support.shape.circle) {
            selector.destroy();
        }
    });

    /**
     * When user click the indicator of Selector, drawer will close.
     */
    elSelector.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var target = event.target;

        if (tau.support.shape.circle) {
            // 'ui-selector-indicator' is default indicator class name of Selector component
            if (target.classList.contains("ui-selector-indicator")) {
                tau.closePopup(popupCircle);
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: <div class="ui-content content-padding"><button type="button" class="ui-more">More Options</button></div> half-resolved my problem, it now works both moreoptions and pageindicator, however, it still greatly distorts the page. If the aforementioned div is before #hsectionchanger, the whole page barey appears at the lower end of the watch's screen, whereas if its bellow, it shows the page normaly.. except that literally half of it is gone. By gone I mean its cut as the 'moreoptions' div is overlapping it.

Comment: did you add any padding ?

Comment: style.css: http://pastebin.com/7pwGqnMz

style-main.css: http://pastebin.com/J1MW8Zyx